# Shuffle only the last element of a list

Tags: python, list, shuffle

I'm writing a poker engine that draws from a large number of decks and creates many hands. I wanted to make each hand contain only unique cards, so I implemented a duplication check when creating hands:

```
def draw(self, c):
        """Generate a hand of c cards"""
        y = 0
        while y < c:
            if self.cards[-1] not in drawcards.values():
                drawcards[y] = self.cards.pop()
                y += 1
            else:
                random.shuffle(self.cards)

        return drawcards
```

This works perfectly, except for the fact that having to `random.shuffle(self.cards)` (which is often extremely large) repeatedly has significantly slowed down my hand output.

Is there a way to shuffle only the final element of my `cards` list without using `copy()` (that would also be taxing on memory)?

(drawcards is predefined as an empty dictionary)

Comment: What does it mean to shuffle a single thing? (Also, what is `self.cards`?)

Comment: `self.cards` is a list of many many cards. the cards are hashable and comparable in terms of equality. And by shuffle a single thing, I mean move it to another place in the list without worrying about shuffling the other elements (i.e. switch the place of 2 elements, a random one and the ultimate one)

Comment: I don't know your business logic, but why can't you just shuffle once then take `[0:n]` from the cards for the first hand, `[n:2*n]` for the second, etc.? Or use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the index of a random element that is not the last:

```
index = random.randint(0, (len(self.cards) - 1))
```

Then just switch the two elements:

```
self.cards[index], self.cards[-1] = self.cards[-1], self.cards[index]
```

Comment: should it be between 1 and len(self.cards) so that it has no chance of being 0 - 1 = -1?

Comment: The range of `index` will be from 0 to the length of the deck - 1, not (0 to the length of the deck) - 1. Your suggestion would mean that `index` could refer to any card between the second and the last inclusive, assuming that `self.cards[0]` refers to the *first* card.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanation. I'd put parentheses around the second argument to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert an item at a random location in your list, then use `self.cards.insert(random.randint(0, len(self.cards)), card)`.

Note that doing so would be O(n) and would have the same runtime complexity as `random.shuffle(self.cards)`.

Alternatively, you could do:

```
self.cards.append(item)
last_index = len(self.cards) - 1
random_index = random.randint(0, last_index)

# Swap elements.
self.cards[random_index], self.cards[last_index] = \
    self.cards[last_index], self.cards[random_index]
```

Which should be faster than inserting into the middle of a list.  However, it might feel questionable since it involves moving some other card to the end. (But since the deck is supposed to be shuffled, it shouldn't actually matter.)

Comment: Swapping would be O(1) time and inserting would be O(n). I think swapping would generally be much preferred.